# Display current time with time zone in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, time, timezone

I'm trying to display the local time on my system with the TimeZone. How can I display time in this format the simplest way possible on any system?:

Time: 8:00:34 AM EST

I'm currently using the following script:

```
$localtz = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::Local | Select-Object -expandproperty Id
if ($localtz -match "Eastern") {$x = " EST"}
if ($localtz -match "Pacific") {$x = " PST"}
if ($localtz -match "Central") {$x = " CST"}
"Time: " + (Get-Date).Hour + ":" + (Get-Date).Minute + ":" + (Get-Date).Second + $x
```

I'd like to be able to display the time without relying on simple logic, but be able to give the local timezone on any system.

Comment: Note that there are more than one time zone name that contains the word "Eastern", so simple matches like this will break. For example, there is "SA Eastern Standard Time" and "AUS Eastern Standard Time".

Comment: A side comment... You really shouldn't call "Get-Date" 3 times.  While it happens really fast, there is a microsecond possibility that the minute hasn't rolled forward when you get that time, but it has rolled forward by the time you get the time for the second value.  So rather than seeing 8:00:59 => 8:01:00, you get a strange 8:00:59 => 8:00:00.  It will correct itself on the next cycle.  A better form is:  (Get-Date -Format "HH:mm:ss")

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While this is a bit ... naive perhaps, it's one way to get *an* abbreviation without a switch statement:

```
[Regex]::Replace([System.TimeZoneInfo]::Local.StandardName, '([A-Z])\w+\s*', '$1')
```

My regular expression probably leaves something to be desired.

The output of the above for my time zone is `EST`. I did some looking as I wanted to see what the value would be for other GMT offset settings, but .NET doesn't seem to have very good links between `DateTime` and `TimeZoneInfo`, so I couldn't just programmatically run through them all to check. This might not work properly for some of the strings that come back for `StandardName`.

**EDIT:** I did some more investigation changing the time zone on my computer manually to check this and a `TimeZoneInfo` for `GMT+12` looks like this:

```
PS> [TimeZoneInfo]::Local

Id                         : UTC+12
DisplayName                : (GMT+12:00) Coordinated Universal Time+12
StandardName               : UTC+12
DaylightName               : UTC+12
BaseUtcOffset              : 12:00:00
SupportsDaylightSavingTime : False
```

Which produces this result for my code:

```
PS> [Regex]::Replace([System.TimeZoneInfo]::Local.StandardName, '([A-Z])\w+\s*', '$1')
U+12
```

So, I guess you'd have to detect whether the `StandardName` appears to be a set of words or just offset designation because there's no standard name for it.

The less problematic ones outside the US appear to follow the three-word format:

```
PS> [TimeZoneInfo]::Local

Id                         : Tokyo Standard Time
DisplayName                : (GMT+09:00) Osaka, Sapporo, Tokyo
StandardName               : Tokyo Standard Time
DaylightName               : Tokyo Daylight Time
BaseUtcOffset              : 09:00:00
SupportsDaylightSavingTime : False

PS> [Regex]::Replace([System.TimeZoneInfo]::Local.StandardName, '([A-Z])\w+\s*', '$1')
TST
```

Comment: @Ken I was a little embarassed at it, but I'm glad it did the trick :).

Comment: `SA Pacific Standard Time` becomes `SPST`; which isn't really accurate. The information you gave was very helpful though. I decided to just settle on getting the minute offset:
`[System.TimeZone]::CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset([datetime]::Now).TotalMinutes`

Answer (score 9):

You should look into [`DateTime` format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97x6twsz%28VS.90%29.aspx). Although I'm not sure they can return a time zone short name, you can easily get an offset from UTC.

```
$formatteddate = "{0:h:mm:ss tt zzz}" -f (get-date)
```

This returns:

```
8:00:34 AM -04:00
```

Comment: I appreciate the help with formatting. However, I still have to figure out a way to associate the Time Zone.

Answer (score 6):

Be loath to define another datetime format! Use an existing one, such as [RFC 1123](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1123.txt). There's even a PowerShell shortcut!

```
Get-Date -format r
```

> Thu, 14 Jun 2012 16:44:18 GMT

Ref.: *[Get-Date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Get-Date)*

Comment: Should be noted that this is not very accurate: currently reports `GMT` when it is really `BST` (one hour ahead of GMT).

Comment: But this is not correct as the current Time Zone is not GMT. I had previously using format but it always gives GMT instead of the correct Time Zone.

Comment: You get GMT regardless of your time zone, it is hard coded - (Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.RFC1123Pattern,

Comment: -format u gives you the correct universal time, the '-g' API is broken IMO

Answer (score 3):

This is a better answer:

```
$A = Get-Date                    #Returns local date/time
$B = $A.ToUniversalTime()        #Convert it to UTC

# Figure out your current offset from UTC
$Offset = [TimeZoneInfo]::Local | Select BaseUtcOffset   

#Add the Offset
$C = $B + $Offset.BaseUtcOffset
$C.ToString()
```

Output:
3/20/2017 11:55:55 PM

Comment: This for some reason wasn't good enough on my system.. it ended up still being an hour off

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any object that can do the work for you. You could wrap the logic in a function:

```
function Get-MyDate{

    $tz = switch -regex ([System.TimeZoneInfo]::Local.Id){
        Eastern    {'EST'; break}
        Pacific    {'PST'; break}
        Central    {'CST'; break}
    }

    "Time: {0:T} $tz" -f (Get-Date)
}

Get-MyDate
```

Or even take the initials of the time zone id:

```
$tz = -join ([System.TimeZoneInfo]::Local.Id.Split() | Foreach-Object {$_[0]})
"Time: {0:T} $tz" -f (Get-Date)
```

Comment: Remember to call `IsDaylightSavingTime` to check whether to look at the `StandardName` (I think this is the same as the `Id`, but unclear if always true) or `DaylightName` property. Also you need to handle the default case for all the other timezones.

Comment: Gotcha, no biggie, in this case you'll get just the time (unless you want to print a default value) :)

Answer (score 0):

I just combined several scripts and finally was able to run the script in my domain controller.

The script provides the output of time and timezone for all the machines connected under the domain.
We had a major issue with our application servers and used this script to cross check the time and timezone.

```
# The below scripts provides the time and time zone for the connected machines in a domain
# Appends the output to a text file with the time stamp
# Checks if the host is reachable or not via a ping command

Start-Transcript -path C:\output.txt -append
$ldapSearcher = New-Object directoryservices.directorysearcher;
$ldapSearcher.filter = "(objectclass=computer)";
$computers = $ldapSearcher.findall();

foreach ($computer in $computers)
{
    $compname = $computer.properties["name"]
    $ping = gwmi win32_pingstatus -f "Address = '$compname'"
    $compname
    if ($ping.statuscode -eq 0)
    {
        try
        {
            $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
            Write-Host “Attempting to determine timezone information for $compname…”
            $Timezone = Get-WMIObject -class Win32_TimeZone -ComputerName $compname

            $remoteOSInfo = gwmi win32_OperatingSystem -computername $compname
            [datetime]$remoteDateTime = $remoteOSInfo.convertToDatetime($remoteOSInfo.LocalDateTime)

            if ($Timezone)
            {
                foreach ($item in $Timezone)
                {
                    $TZDescription  = $Timezone.Description
                    $TZDaylightTime = $Timezone.DaylightName
                    $TZStandardTime = $Timezone.StandardName
                    $TZStandardTime = $Timezone.StandardTime
                }
                Write-Host "Timezone is set to $TZDescription`nTime and Date is $remoteDateTime`n**********************`n"
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Host ("Something went wrong")
            }
         }
         catch
         {
             Write-Host ("You have insufficient rights to query the computer or the RPC server is not available.")
         }
         finally
         {
             $ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
         }
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host ("Host $compname is not reachable from ping `n")
    }
}

Stop-Transcript
```

Answer (score 0):

Russia, France, Norway, Germany:

```
get-date -format "HH:mm:ss ddd dd'.'MM'.'yy' г.' zzz"
```

Output for Russian time zone: 22:47:27 Чт 21.11.19 г. +03:00

Others - just change the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a internet connection... API

```
Function tzAbbreviation {
    Try {
        $webData = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip" -UseBasicParsing -TimeoutSec 3 -ErrorAction Stop
        $Content = ConvertFrom-Json $webData.Content

        Return $($Content.Abbreviation)
    }
    Catch {}
}

$tzAbbreviation = tzAbbreviation
```

In the Netherlands...

Output: CET

Answer (score 0):

**Subtract What is seen by the script**

Sometimes the TimeZoneInfo Local is different than what the script is finding. For example I noticed that mine was off by one hour where -5 was reported but the PS script (get-date) was -4. Also where possible use [datetime]::UtcNow instead of get-date.

**Explaination:**

Instead of relying on the local time  '[TimeZoneInfo]::Local | Select BaseUtcOffset', figure out the difference in the script between two dates

```
  ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() - (Get-Date)).TotalHours
```

- Note: this assumes West of UTC, otherwise reverse the math or change to +.

Answer (score 0):

This is a funny set of answers, because so much really depends on how you want to view an abbreviated form of the time zone.  Some with numeric offsets, some just text.  This was my solution for an alphanumeric time zone abbreviation, with handling for daylight savings time, and handling if it doesn't have a "standard name".  I've tested the time zones that are available in a US version of Windows 10, and while they aren't all unique or accurate, it works for my needs.  I'd appreciate any feedback:

```
function Get-TimeZoneAbbreviation {
    [CmdletBinding()] param ([TimeZoneInfo]$timeZoneInfo = [TimeZoneInfo]::Local, $daylightSavingsTime = $null)
    
    $result = ""
    # If DST parameter is left empty, calculate DST from current time in that time zone.
    if ($daylightSavingsTime -eq $null) {
        $daylightSavingsTime = $timeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime([TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeFromUtc([DateTime]::UtcNow, $timeZoneInfo))
    }
    # If DST is supplied as true, but isn't supported return null.
    elseif ($daylightSavingsTime -and !$timeZoneInfo.SupportsDaylightSavingTime) {
        return $null
    }
    
    # Get standard or daylight name.
    $tzFullName = $timeZoneInfo.StandardName
    if ($daylightSavingsTime) {
        $tzFullName = $timeZoneInfo.DaylightName
    }
    
    # If name doesn't have multiple words then just return the name.
    $tzSplit = $tzFullName.Split(" ")
    if ($tzSplit.Length -eq 1) {
        return $tzFullName
    }
    
    # Return abbreviation as first character of each word.
    foreach ($tzC in $tzSplit) {
        $result += [regex]::Replace($tzC, "[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]", "").Substring(0, 1)
    }
    return $result
}
```

Usage (I only specify strings so I can use PadRight for output):

```
# Output for original question:
[string]$tzaLocalNow = @(Get-TimeZoneAbbreviation)
"Local Time Now:  " + @(Get-Date -Format "HH:mm:ss ") + $tzaLocalNow

# Output using DST parameter
[string]$tzaLocalStandard = @(Get-TimeZoneAbbreviation -daylightSavingsTime $false)
[string]$tzaLocalDaylight = @(Get-TimeZoneAbbreviation -daylightSavingsTime $true)
Write-Host @("`n" + $tzaLocalNow.PadRight(10) + $tzaLocalStandard.PadRight(10) + $tzaLocalDaylight + "`n")

# Output table of all system time zone abbreviations.
foreach ($tz in (Get-TimeZone -ListAvailable)) {
    [string]$tzaNow = @(Get-TimeZoneAbbreviation $tz)
    [string]$tzaStandard = @(Get-TimeZoneAbbreviation $tz $false)
    [string]$tzaDaylight = @(Get-TimeZoneAbbreviation $tz $true)
    Write-Host @($tzaNow.PadRight(10) + $tzaStandard.PadRight(10) + $tzaDaylight)
}
```

And so that you don't have to run it yourself, this table shows the results in the right-most columns:

```
DisplayName                                                    Offset     St    Ds
==================================================================================
(UTC-12:00) International Date Line West                          -12    DST      
(UTC-11:00) Coordinated Universal Time-11                         -11 UTC-11      
(UTC-10:00) Aleutian Islands                                      -10    AST   ADT
(UTC-10:00) Hawaii                                                -10    HST      
(UTC-09:30) Marquesas Islands                                     -09    MST      
(UTC-09:00) Alaska                                                -09    AST   ADT
(UTC-09:00) Coordinated Universal Time-09                         -09 UTC-09      
(UTC-08:00) Baja California                                       -08   PSTM  PDTM
(UTC-08:00) Coordinated Universal Time-08                         -08 UTC-08      
(UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)                            -08    PST   PDT
(UTC-07:00) Arizona                                               -07   UMST      
(UTC-07:00) La Paz, Mazatlan                                      -07   MSTM  MDTM
(UTC-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada)                           -07    MST   MDT
(UTC-07:00) Yukon                                                 -07    YST   YDT
(UTC-06:00) Central America                                       -06   CAST      
(UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)                            -06    CST   CDT
(UTC-06:00) Easter Island                                         -06   EIST  EIDT
(UTC-06:00) Guadalajara, Mexico City, Monterrey                   -06   CSTM  CDTM
(UTC-06:00) Saskatchewan                                          -06   CCST      
(UTC-05:00) Bogota, Lima, Quito, Rio Branco                       -05   SPST      
(UTC-05:00) Chetumal                                              -05   ESTM  EDTM
(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)                            -05    EST   EDT
(UTC-05:00) Haiti                                                 -05    HST   HDT
(UTC-05:00) Havana                                                -05    CST   CDT
(UTC-05:00) Indiana (East)                                        -05   UEST  UEDT
(UTC-05:00) Turks and Caicos                                      -05  TaCST TaCDT
(UTC-04:00) Asuncion                                              -04    PST   PDT
(UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)                                -04    AST   ADT
(UTC-04:00) Caracas                                               -04    VST   VDT
(UTC-04:00) Cuiaba                                                -04   CBST  CBDT
(UTC-04:00) Georgetown, La Paz, Manaus, San Juan                  -04   SWST      
(UTC-04:00) Santiago                                              -04   PSST  PSDT
(UTC-03:30) Newfoundland                                          -03    NST   NDT
(UTC-03:00) Araguaina                                             -03    TST   TDT
(UTC-03:00) Brasilia                                              -03  ESAST ESADT
(UTC-03:00) Cayenne, Fortaleza                                    -03   SEST      
(UTC-03:00) City of Buenos Aires                                  -03    AST   ADT
(UTC-03:00) Greenland                                             -03    GST   GDT
(UTC-03:00) Montevideo                                            -03    MST   MDT
(UTC-03:00) Punta Arenas                                          -03    MST   MDT
(UTC-03:00) Saint Pierre and Miquelon                             -03   SPST  SPDT
(UTC-03:00) Salvador                                              -03    BST   BDT
(UTC-02:00) Coordinated Universal Time-02                         -02 UTC-02      
(UTC-02:00) Mid-Atlantic - Old                                    -02    MST   MDT
(UTC-01:00) Azores                                                -01    AST   ADT
(UTC-01:00) Cabo Verde Is.                                        -01   CVST      
(UTC) Coordinated Universal Time                                   00    CUT      
(UTC+00:00) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London                      00    GST   GDT
(UTC+00:00) Monrovia, Reykjavik                                    00    GST      
(UTC+00:00) Sao Tome                                               00   STST  STDT
(UTC+01:00) Casablanca                                             00    MST   MDT
(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna      +01   WEST  WEDT
(UTC+01:00) Belgrade, Bratislava, Budapest, Ljubljana, Prague     +01   CEST  CEDT
(UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris                   +01    RST   RDT
(UTC+01:00) Sarajevo, Skopje, Warsaw, Zagreb                      +01   CEST  CEDT
(UTC+01:00) West Central Africa                                   +01  WCAST      
(UTC+02:00) Athens, Bucharest                                     +02    GST   GDT
(UTC+02:00) Beirut                                                +02   MEST  MEDT
(UTC+02:00) Cairo                                                 +02    EST   EDT
(UTC+02:00) Chisinau                                              +02   EEST  EEDT
(UTC+02:00) Damascus                                              +02    SST   SDT
(UTC+02:00) Gaza, Hebron                                          +02  WBGST WBGDT
(UTC+02:00) Harare, Pretoria                                      +02   SAST      
(UTC+02:00) Helsinki, Kyiv, Riga, Sofia, Tallinn, Vilnius         +02    FST   FDT
(UTC+02:00) Jerusalem                                             +02    JST   JDT
(UTC+02:00) Juba                                                  +02   SSST  SSDT
(UTC+02:00) Kaliningrad                                           +02  RT1ST RT1DT
(UTC+02:00) Khartoum                                              +02    SST   SDT
(UTC+02:00) Tripoli                                               +02    LST   LDT
(UTC+02:00) Windhoek                                              +02    NST   NDT
(UTC+03:00) Amman                                                 +03    JST   JDT
(UTC+03:00) Baghdad                                               +03    AST   ADT
(UTC+03:00) Istanbul                                              +03    TST   TDT
(UTC+03:00) Kuwait, Riyadh                                        +03    AST      
(UTC+03:00) Minsk                                                 +03    BST   BDT
(UTC+03:00) Moscow, St. Petersburg                                +03  RT2ST RT2DT
(UTC+03:00) Nairobi                                               +03   EAST      
(UTC+03:00) Volgograd                                             +03    VST   VDT
(UTC+03:30) Tehran                                                +03    IST   IDT
(UTC+04:00) Abu Dhabi, Muscat                                     +04    AST      
(UTC+04:00) Astrakhan, Ulyanovsk                                  +04    AST   ADT
(UTC+04:00) Baku                                                  +04    AST   ADT
(UTC+04:00) Izhevsk, Samara                                       +04  RT3ST RT3DT
(UTC+04:00) Port Louis                                            +04    MST   MDT
(UTC+04:00) Saratov                                               +04    SST   SDT
(UTC+04:00) Tbilisi                                               +04    GST      
(UTC+04:00) Yerevan                                               +04    CST   CDT
(UTC+04:30) Kabul                                                 +04    AST      
(UTC+05:00) Ashgabat, Tashkent                                    +05   WAST      
(UTC+05:00) Ekaterinburg                                          +05  RT4ST RT4DT
(UTC+05:00) Islamabad, Karachi                                    +05    PST   PDT
(UTC+05:00) Qyzylorda                                             +05    QST   QDT
(UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi                   +05    IST      
(UTC+05:30) Sri Jayawardenepura                                   +05   SLST      
(UTC+05:45) Kathmandu                                             +05    NST      
(UTC+06:00) Astana                                                +06   CAST      
(UTC+06:00) Dhaka                                                 +06    BST   BDT
(UTC+06:00) Omsk                                                  +06    OST   ODT
(UTC+06:30) Yangon (Rangoon)                                      +06    MST      
(UTC+07:00) Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta                               +07   SAST      
(UTC+07:00) Barnaul, Gorno-Altaysk                                +07    AST   ADT
(UTC+07:00) Hovd                                                  +07   WMST  WMDT
(UTC+07:00) Krasnoyarsk                                           +07  RT6ST RT6DT
(UTC+07:00) Novosibirsk                                           +07    NST   NDT
(UTC+07:00) Tomsk                                                 +07    TST   TDT
(UTC+08:00) Beijing, Chongqing, Hong Kong, Urumqi                 +08    CST      
(UTC+08:00) Irkutsk                                               +08  RT7ST RT7DT
(UTC+08:00) Kuala Lumpur, Singapore                               +08   MPST      
(UTC+08:00) Perth                                                 +08   WAST  WADT
(UTC+08:00) Taipei                                                +08    TST      
(UTC+08:00) Ulaanbaatar                                           +08    UST   UDT
(UTC+08:45) Eucla                                                 +08  ACWST      
(UTC+09:00) Chita                                                 +09    TST   TDT
(UTC+09:00) Osaka, Sapporo, Tokyo                                 +09    TST      
(UTC+09:00) Pyongyang                                             +09   NKST  NKDT
(UTC+09:00) Seoul                                                 +09    KST      
(UTC+09:00) Yakutsk                                               +09  RT8ST RT8DT
(UTC+09:30) Adelaide                                              +09   CAST  CADT
(UTC+09:30) Darwin                                                +09   ACST      
(UTC+10:00) Brisbane                                              +10   EAST      
(UTC+10:00) Canberra, Melbourne, Sydney                           +10   AEST  AEDT
(UTC+10:00) Guam, Port Moresby                                    +10   WPST      
(UTC+10:00) Hobart                                                +10    TST   TDT
(UTC+10:00) Vladivostok                                           +10  RT9ST RT9DT
(UTC+10:30) Lord Howe Island                                      +10   LHST  LHDT
(UTC+11:00) Bougainville Island                                   +11    BST   BDT
(UTC+11:00) Chokurdakh                                            +11  RT1ST RT1DT
(UTC+11:00) Magadan                                               +11    MST   MDT
(UTC+11:00) Norfolk Island                                        +11    NST   NDT
(UTC+11:00) Sakhalin                                              +11    SST   SDT
(UTC+11:00) Solomon Is., New Caledonia                            +11   CPST      
(UTC+12:00) Anadyr, Petropavlovsk-Kamchatsky                      +12  RT1ST RT1DT
(UTC+12:00) Auckland, Wellington                                  +12   NZST  NZDT
(UTC+12:00) Coordinated Universal Time+12                         +12 UTC+12      
(UTC+12:00) Fiji                                                  +12    FST   FDT
(UTC+12:00) Petropavlovsk-Kamchatsky - Old                        +12    KST   KDT
(UTC+12:45) Chatham Islands                                       +12   CIST  CIDT
(UTC+13:00) Coordinated Universal Time+13                         +13 UTC+13      
(UTC+13:00) Nuku'alofa                                            +13    TST   TDT
(UTC+13:00) Samoa                                                 +13    SST   SDT
(UTC+14:00) Kiritimati Island                                     +14   LIST
```