# Classic ASP - Display List of Timezones using powershell

Tags: powershell, asp-classic

Is there anyway to display system timezone using powershell GET-Timezone -ListAvailble. My requirements is to display this in a dropdownlist in an ASP page. Using .net com is not an option for me now, and even SQL server sys.time_zone_info.

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell Display current time with time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035905/powershell-display-current-time-with-time-zone)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dealing with timezones in vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37592262/692942)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Shell.Exec](https://ss64.com/vb/exec.html) to call the powershell command and read from the standard output.

The powershell part is from [Lee_Dailey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53717643/1682881)

```
<%
Set objShell = server.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objExec = objShell.Exec("cmd /c powershell [System.TimeZoneInfo]::GetSystemTimeZones().DisplayName")
Set objStdOut = objExec.StdOut


Response.write "<select name=""Timezones"">"

While Not objStdOut.AtEndOfStream
   Response.write "<option>" & objStdOut.ReadLine & "</option>"
Wend

Response.write "</select>"

%>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Get-TimeZone`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-timezone?view=powershell-6)

> Gets the current time zone or a list of available time zones.

If you run it without parameters it gives the current timezone on the host computer.

Example output:

```
Id                         : GMT Standard Time
DisplayName                : (UTC+00:00) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London
StandardName               : GMT Standard Time
DaylightName               : GMT Daylight Time
BaseUtcOffset              : 00:00:00
SupportsDaylightSavingTime : True
```

Comment: How does that help them display it in a Classic ASP page?

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I also want to know how to call this from ASP Classic and display this in a dropdownlist, my knowledge in ASP classic is not that good.

Answer (score 0):

if all you want is the offset/name for each timezone known to the current system, this will give that list ...

```
[System.TimeZoneInfo]::GetSystemTimeZones().DisplayName
```

as much as some may object, that *is* powershell. [*grin*]

Comment: How does that help them display it in a Classic ASP page?

Comment: you said you wanted powershell code to get the list. this gets that list with powershell code ... [*grin*] store the list in a $Var and use that to fill the ASP list.

Comment: My point is, getting the list in powershell has been covered before. Plus, it’s only part of the answer in which case it’s a duplicate.

Comment: @Lankymart - ah! i completely misunderstood your question. i thot it was about powershell, not about how to code in ASP. i think you may have made an error in using the powershell tag for this. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lankymart - ah! the powershell tag led me to misunderstand your intent. whoever added that may have made an error.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I also want to know how to use this from ASP Classic and display this in a dropdownlist, im not doing this in a standalone powershell script.